# Is there a method in Java that is capable of throwing ever exception type?

Tags: java, methods, exception

Can anyone think of a method in Java that would be capable of throwing every exception type? It would be a **really** horrible method, I know, but I'm curious if anyone has done it.

I ask because in my class today we were talking about exceptions and I thought it would be entertaining to see a method capable of throwing every single type.

Comment: But you can: myHorribleMethod(...) throws Throwable

Comment: Sure...write one that explicitly throws each based on certain conditions.

Comment: User's can define their own exception...what is it supposed to do then?

Comment: I think the entertainment value of this is being over-estimated.

Comment: If only I could post some of the production code I see every day ...

Comment: There's nothing *that* horrible about this. Or at least, about throwing `Exception`. (There's not much reason to ever throw `Error`s manually, and `throws Throwable` usually indicates the author needs to brush up on the basics.) For example if you make a callback-based API, it's common to allow the callback method to throw any exception which is usually wrapped in an exception specific to your API. (The callback-based APIs that don't allow this are really really frustrating. Like `Runnable`.)

Answer (score 4):

An exception is something that can be custom-made. What you are asking if having a method that throws a generic Throwable object. With this declaration, any existing exception or newly created exception is 'handled' by the throws statement

```
public void myMethod throws Throwable{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

New "`Exception`" types can be created by the programmer, so no you can never have a function that explicitly throws every `Exception` ever since there are an infinite amount of `Exception`s possible.

You can `throw Throwable`, but that doesn't gain you anything.

Catching every possible Exception *is* possible though, by catching Throwable, maybe that is what you meant to ask...

Answer (score 0):

No.

The nearest thing would be:

```
public void horribleMethod() thorw Throwable;
```

But this will throw a generic type. If I ever read such a mthod signature, I would slap the programmers head to the keyboard.